# iOS - anchor view to the top of the screen, behind status bar

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, nslayoutconstraint, nslayoutanchor

I've a CollectionViewController with the default status bar and all it's embedded in a NavigationController.

I'm trying to reproduce an effect in which I have a View anchored to the top of the screen, since my navController is fully transparent and my status bar is also transparent, but somehow when I anchor my view to the `topAnchor` it stays clipped to the NavigationController bottomAnchor, because it 'thinks' the top of the screen is the navController's bottom.

I managed to bypass this simply after anchoring the view to the top, I gave it a negative topPadding and it now is where I desired it to be.

I know there's a way to extend the layout to the top screen but I can't figure it out.

Can you give me an hint?

I'm trying this:

[image: desired]

I'm getting this:

[image: result]

The white space is the status bar height + NavigationController height

Thanks

Comment: Are you adding constraints in Interface Builder / Storyboard? Or via code?

Comment: I don't use storyboards, everything is hand-coded

Comment: Since the CollectionView is embedded in the NavController and I set the NavController and the status bar to be transparent I wondered if I could set the start position maybe of the collectionView to be right on top of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this pins my `UIImageView` to the Top of the screen... underneath the nav and status bars. Shouldn't be any different with a collection view:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintWithItem:imageView
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                           toItem:self.view
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                           multiplier:1
                           constant:0];
```

Edit: Sorry, was working in an Obj-C project... here it is in Swift:

```
    let img = UIImage(named: "Man")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: img)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.view.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true

    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

[image]

and... here it is with a collection view also (kinda hard to tell with a plain screen-cap):

```
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white

    let img = UIImage(named: "Man")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: img)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.view.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true

    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = .clear

    cv.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "defaultCell")
    cv.dataSource = self

    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(cv)

    cv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9).isActive = true
    cv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0).isActive = true

    cv.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    cv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

[image]

Comment: I was just converting it to Swift. Let me give a try :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a ViewControllers contents view to extend under the top/bottom bars, you can use the Extend Edges Under Top Bars/Under Bottom Bars settings in Interface Builder.

Try using this

**ObjectiveC:**

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

**Swift3:**

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

*Hope this may help you :)*

Comment: hmm.. even though I didn't knew this was possible , thanks for the tip. But this is not what I'm trying to achieve.
The result that I'm trying is something like the scrollview of the collection view starts on the top of the screen and not to start at the bottom of the navigation controller

Answer (score -1):

```
class DetailsPage : UIViewController {

    let topView:UIView = UIView()
    let topSliderImage:UIImageView = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setUI()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { 
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage() 
    }

    func setUI(){

        self.view.addSubview(topSliderImage)
        topSliderImage.image = UIImage(named: "img-1")
        topSliderImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        topSliderImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topSliderImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        topSliderImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        topSliderImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true
    }
}
```

[image]